# Reduce Map values concurrently

Tags: scala, concurrency

I have Map of String keys and Seq[Int] values. How can I reduce the Seq[Int] to single Int value concurrently for each key.

for example:

```
 Map("xxx" -> (1 to 10), "yyy" -> (100 to 200))
```

should be reduced to

```
 Map("xxx" -> 55, "yyy" -> 15150)
```

concurrently for each key in the Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parallel collections both for the Map and the Range
e.g.

```
val x= Map("xxx" -> (1 to 10), "yyy" -> (100 to 200)) 
x.par.map{case (a,b)=>(a,b.par.sum)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should work using Futures.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

val data = Map("xxx" -> (1 to 10), "yyy" -> (100 to 200))
Await.result(Future.sequence(data.map({ case (x,y) => Future { x -> y.sum } })), Duration.Inf).toMap

res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(xxx -> 55, yyy -> 15150)
```